# Resizing swapchain causes Bitmap not to be usable (SharpDX, directX)

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

I want to resize my swapchain on screen resizing on my windows form application. When I do that, I need to dispose my older deviceContext, buffer, target etc...

Look at the code below :

```
Public Overrides Sub Resize(Width As Integer, Height As Integer)
    m_backBuffer.Dispose()
    m_d2dContext.Dispose()
    m_2dTarget.Dispose()


    m_swapChain.ResizeBuffers(2, Width, Height, Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, SwapChainFlags.None)
    m_backBuffer = m_swapChain.GetBackBuffer(Of Surface)(0)
    Dim properties As BitmapProperties = New BitmapProperties(New SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, SharpDX.Direct2D1.AlphaMode.Premultiplied), 96, 96)

    Dim dxgiDevice As SharpDX.DXGI.Device = m_device.QueryInterface(Of SharpDX.DXGI.Device)()

    Dim d2dDevice As SharpDX.Direct2D1.Device = New SharpDX.Direct2D1.Device(dxgiDevice)
    m_d2dContext = New SharpDX.Direct2D1.DeviceContext(d2dDevice, SharpDX.Direct2D1.DeviceContextOptions.None)

    m_2dTarget = New SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap(m_d2dContext, m_backBuffer, properties)
    m_d2dContext.Target = m_2dTarget

    CType(m_Context, GpuDrawingContext).setRenderTarget(m_d2dContext)

End Sub
```

The problem when I do that, is that the bitmap I had previously created to display on screen needed a DeviceContext as a parameter for their creation. However, now that I am instanciating a new DeviceContext on resizing, I get the error WrongFactory when I want to draw the bitmap on the deviceContext because their aren't created with the same DeviceContext from where we want to draw them.

Any solutions for the resize function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fundamentally wrong. When handling resize you don't really need to call anything but `ResizeBuffers`. And you definitely don't need to dispose of `m_d2dContext` as typically you keep the same one for the lifetime of your application. The rest of your code actually belong to frame rendering, typically at each iteration you do the following:

- obtain backbuffer (note that it should not be cached because after each Present swap chain will return different backbuffer surface)
- create d2d bitmap object for backbuffer surface
- dispose of backbuffer
- set this d2d bitmap object as render targer of d2d device context
- dispose of d2d bitmap (it is still alive as it is being used by dc)
- begin draw
- draw...
- end draw
- reset d2d device context render target
- present fresh frame